# splitting JSON into two different objects using identifier

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON which looks like:

```
[
   {
      "username": "saurabhu",
      "tenant_name": "abc_c1e3e096-6e95-4b84",
      "project_domain_name": "aa",
      "user_domain_name": "aa",
      "password": "saurabhp",
      "roles": [
         "admin"
      ]
   },
   {
      "username": "saurabhu",
      "tenant_name": "def_c1e3e096-6e95-4b84",
      "project_domain_name": "aa",
      "user_domain_name": "aa",
      "password": "saurabhp",
      "roles": [
         "ResellerAdmin",
         "heat_stack_owner",
         "Member"
      ]
   },
   {
      "username": "saurabhu",
      "tenant_name": "c_c1e3e096-6e95-4b84",
      "project_domain_name": "aa",
      "user_domain_name": "aa",
      "password": "saurabhp",
      "roles": [
         "ResellerAdmin",
         "heat_stack_owner",
         "Member"
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to format it like:

```
{
    "fool": {
        "admin": {
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "pa55word",
            "tenant_name": "demo"
        },
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "normal_user",
                "password": "password",
                "user_domain_name": "Default",
                "project_name": "normal_project",
                "project_domain_name": "Default"
            },
            {
                "username": "normal_user2",
                "password": "password",
                "user_domain_name": "Default",
                "project_name": "normal_project",
                "project_domain_name": "Default"
            }
        ]       
    }
}
```

I am able to split it into a single object based on the admin role using this:

```
.[] | if .roles[]=="admin" then {"username","password",project_name: .tenant_name} else {"username","password", "user_domain_name", project_name: .tenant_name, "project_domain_name" } end
```

but how can I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

With ***jq*** you can :

- store a temporary value in a variable using `. as $VARIABLENAME`
- iterate over a array  using `map`
- overwrite value with `|=`
- apply a condition on every value of array and return the logical or using `any`

A possible solution can be :

```
jq ' . as $alluser | 
   { "admin" : 
       $alluser |map(if .roles| any( . == "admin") then .roles|= empty else empty end),
      "users"  : 
       $alluser |map(if .roles| any( . == "admin") then empty else .roles|= empty end) } ' \
  your_datas.json
```

ps :
  manual of jq is here 
   https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/